# Maximum allowed oil burning of Mercedes W203

Tags: oil, mercedes-benz, oil-consumption

I have a Mercedes W203 180 Kompressor car.

My question is what is the maximum allowed oil burning of this car per 1000km?

Answer (score 2):

According to this, but you should check with a dealer or th wokshop manual it is about 0.8litres per 1000k :

```
https://mbworld.org/forums/c-class-w203/26775-oil-consumption-concern.html
```